# LINK PREVIOUS AND NEXT POST in a php blog

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I'm a new developer and I'm trying to make work my very simple blog. 
I want to set a previous and a next link to my previous and next articles in the blog. This is my current code.

POSTS CONTROLLER

```
public function move($id)
{
    $post = DB::table('posts')->find($id);

    $previous = DB::table('posts')->where('id', '<', $post->id)->max('id');

    $next = DB::table('posts')->where('id', '>', $post->id)->min('id');

    return view('posts.show')->with('previous', $previous)->with('next', $next);
}
```

WEB.PHP

```
<?php

Route::get('/', 'PostsController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/posts/create', 'PostsController@create');
Route::post('/posts', 'PostsController@store');
//Route::get('/posts/{post}', 'PostsController@show');
Route::get('/posts/tags/{tag}', 'TagsController@index');
Route::post('/posts/{post}/comments','CommentsController@store');

Route::get('/posts/{id}/edit', 'PostsController@edit');
Route::get('/edit/{post}', 'PostsController@update');
Route::patch('/post/{post}', 'PostsController@update');

Route::get('/register', 'RegistrationController@create');
Route::post('/register', 'RegistrationController@store');

Route::get('/login', 'SessionsController@create');
Route::post('/login', 'SessionsController@store');

Route::get('/logout', 'SessionsController@destroy');

Route::get('/posts/{id}', 'PostsController@move');
```

SHOW.BLADE

```
@extends ('layouts.master')

@section ('content')

<div class="col-sm-8 blog-main">
<h1> {{$post->title}}</h1>

@if (count($post->tags))

    <ul>

        @foreach($post->tags as $tag)

            <li>

                <a href="/posts/tags/{{ $tag->name}}">

                {{ $tag->name }}

                </a>

            </li>

        @endforeach

    </ul>

@endif

{{$post->body}}

<hr>

<a href="/posts/{id}/edit">Modifica</a>

<hr>

<div class='comments'>

    <ul class="list-group">

    @foreach ($post->comments as $comment)

        <li class="lista-commenti">

            <strong>

                {{$comment->created_at->diffForHumans()}}: &nbsp;

            </strong>

            {{ $comment -> body}}

        </li>

    @endforeach

    </ul>

</div>

<hr>

<div>

    <div>

        <form method="POST" action="/posts/{{$post->id}}/comments">


            {{csrf_field()}} 

            <div>

                <textarea name="body" placeholder="Il tuo commento" class="form-control" required></textarea>

            </div>



            <div>

                <button type="submit" class="bottone">Invia Commento</button>

            </div>

        </form>

        @include('layouts.errors')

    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <ul>


        <li><a href="http://www.localhost.it/posts/{{ $previous }}"> Previous</a></li>

        <li><a href="http://www.localhost.it/posts/{{ $next }}"> Next</a>
</li>

        </ul>

    </div>

</div>

</div>

@endsection
```

POST.PHP

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Carbon\Carbon;

class Post extends Model
{


public function comments()

{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}

public function user()

{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}


public function addComment($body)

{
    $user_id= auth()->id();

    $this->comments()->create(compact('user_id','body'));
}

public function scopeFilter($query, $filters)

    {

        if(!$filters)

        {
            return $query;
        }

    if ($month = $filters['month']) 
    {

    $query->whereMonth('created_at', Carbon::parse($month)->month);

    }

    if ($year = $filters['year']) {
    $query->whereYear('created_at', $year);
    }
    }


public static function archives()

{

    return static::selectRaw('year(created_at) year, monthname(created_at) month, count(*) published')
                    ->groupBy('year','month')
                    ->orderByRaw('min(created_at) desc')
                    ->get()
                    ->toArray();




}


public function tags(){

    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
}

}
```

This gives me an error about the undefined variables previous and next and also about the www.

Sorry but this is my first post and I can't upload any images. Hope someone can help me.

Thanks

Alessandro

Comment: first you may do this .. `$data['previous'] = DB::table('posts')->where('id', '<', $post->id)->max('id');` same for next .. then `return view('posts.show',$data);`

Answer (score 1):

use `url()` helper method:

```
    <li><a href="{{url('posts/' . $previous)}}"> Previous</a></li>

    <li><a href="{{url('posts/' . $next)}}"> Next</a></li>
```

**Edit:** remove this `Route::get('/posts/{post}', 'PostsController@show');` line or change your code like `move` method in your `show` method.

For your new error, add this line at top-

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

Comment: I tried but he still give me the same errors : 

Undefined variable: previous Undefined variable: next

Comment: Yes, I did. This is the error : 

Undefined variable: previous (View: C:\Users\michela\Desktop\cremascoli alessandro\PROGETTOHELLOGEST\SourceTree-Teo\resources\views\posts\show.blade.php)

Comment: what is the url you are trying that gives this error??

Comment: try `dd($previous)` before return statements in your controller code and see what it gives

Comment: please add your full `web.php`, seems you are using one route and showing other routes implementations

Comment: <?php

Route::get('/', 'PostsController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/posts/create', 'PostsController@create');

Route::post('/posts', 'PostsController@store');

Route::get('/posts/{post}', 'PostsController@show');

Route::get('/posts/tags/{tag}', 'TagsController@index');

Route::post('/posts/{post}/comments','CommentsController@store');

Comment: Route::get('/posts/{id}/edit', 'PostsController@edit');
Route::get('/edit/{post}', 'PostsController@update');
Route::patch('/post/{post}', 'PostsController@update');


Route::get('/register', 'RegistrationController@create');
Route::post('/register', 'RegistrationController@store');


Route::get('/login', 'SessionsController@create');
Route::post('/login', 'SessionsController@store');


Route::get('/logout', 'SessionsController@destroy');

Route::get('/posts/{id}', 'PostsController@move');

Comment: sorry i dont know how to make it looks better :(

Comment: remove this `Route::get('/posts/{post}', 'PostsController@show');` or change your code like move method in your show meethod

Comment: OK, for the first time something change but another error appear.

Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found

he is talking about my controller now

Comment: @alessandrocremascoli add this line at top `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;`

Comment: OMG it works . A number '4' appear into the screen. I'm going to try the link now

Comment: hope everything will be fine now

Comment: another error after I cancel the dd. 

Undefined variable: post (View: C:\Users\michela\Desktop\cremascoli alessandro\PROGETTOHELLOGEST\SourceTree-Teo\resources\views\posts\show.blade.php)

Comment: add with return `->with('post', $post);`

Comment: done. now this : Undefined property: stdClass::$tags (View: C:\Users\michela\Desktop\cremascoli alessandro\PROGETTOHELLOGEST\SourceTree-Teo\resources\views\posts\show.blade.php)

Comment: we can't help you with this as there is nothing called `tags` mentioned in your questions, update your question with your full view code or make a new questions with your new problem

Comment: You right. I didn't think it matters before. I've update with all my code.

Comment: seems its relationship problem, you need to show us your post model and its relationship for better understanding

Comment: do you mean my post.php ? or the full code of postscontroller ?

Comment: rather than this `DB::table('posts')->find($id)` do this `Post::find($id)` and change according to this

Comment: Now everything works except the next and previous when I arrive at the first or last post

Comment: whats the problem now??

Comment: Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message

Comment: add this url at the top of your route file `Route::get('/posts/{id}', 'PostsController@move');` it should solve your problem

Comment: I have the same url in my route file. I have to put in twice ?

Comment: forget it, when you are having error?? is it after clicking the previous button?? or when??

Comment: I have the error when I click NEXT but its the last article and when I click PREVIOUS but its the first one

Comment: make a fresh post with your updated code, that way may be others can help you

Answer (score 0):

When you're going to `post/1`, you're executing the `show` method and not `move`.

Also, change the code to:

```
<li><a href="http://www.localhost.it/posts/{{ $previous }}"> Previous</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.localhost.it/posts/{{ $next }}"> Next</a></li>
```

You've said, "and also about the www". I'm pretty sure you're not getting the error about the `$previous` or `$next` but you get the error about the `www...` because you're trying to use text as variable in your code.

Comment: Oh sorry. I'm very new and I'm still trying to learn as much as possible about this. I've correct my sintax but he give me two errors :

Undefined variable: previous

Undefined variable: next

Comment: Even if you fixed the `www`, it can't give you two errors but just one. Why are you making this up? It's hard to help you when you're doing this instead of telling what exactly is going on (showing the error etc).

Comment: He gives me this error :

Undefined variable: previous (View: C:\Users\michela\Desktop\cremascoli alessandro\PROGETTOHELLOGEST\SourceTree-Teo\resources\views\posts\show.blade.php)

I tried to cancel the "previous" part and he gives me the same error for the "next".

Comment: @alessandrocremascoli When you're going to `post/1`, you're executing the `show` method and not `move`. I've updated the answer.